# Help me solve this predicate logic proof theory: -(∀z)(∃y)Tzy ⊢ (∃z)(∀y)-Tzy

Tags: logic, proof, predicate-logic

-(∀z)(∃y)Tzy ⊢ (∃z)(∀y)-Tzy

Using Lande, (AI,EI,AE,EE,->E,->I,-I,--E,^I,^E,vI,vE) I cannot figure out the proof on this sequent.

Comment: I think such questions are off-topic here and belong to https://mathoverflow.net/

Comment: Is "-" meant to be negation? If so, why not start with an easier problem Ax[Px] -> ~Ex[~Px]? Where "Ax" is forall, "Ex" is exists, and "~" is negation

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is not a homework forum

Answer (score 1):

-(∀z)(∃y)Tzy ⊢ (∃z)(∀y)-Tzy

quantifier negation to z:
(∃z)~(∃y)Tzy

quantifier negation to y

(∃z)(∀y)~Tzy